# Yii CTabView only first page shows a view

Tags: yii, highcharts

im using a CTabView to display some HighCharts graphics, but only the first tab gets rendered.
i see a blank tab for each of the other ones, 
and sometimes i get javascript  errors from HighCharts (`tickPosition not defined`)

is the javascript for HighCharts being published properly to the different views?
why would the first view work and not the other ones?

```
$this->widget('CTabView', array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        'tab1'=>array(
            'title'=>'Contract Extensions per Group',
            'view'=>'reportGroupExtensionsStack',
            'data'=>array('model'=>$model),
        ),
        'ta1'=>array(
            'title'=>'Gender of Assistants',
            'view'=>'reportGender',
           'data'=>array('model'=>$model),
       ),
   ),
));
```

Comment: Have you any live demo of it? Do you try to initialize chart in hidden div / tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't work in hidden/not displayed containers. 
Take a look: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10712

So possible solution is to render all chart or outside the containers, and move them to the specific tab when clicked, or when tab is clicked - then render chart.